# Using one array as a multi-dimensional index into another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

Say I have two arrays, `G` and `gamma`.

```py
>>> G
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>> gamma
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27]]])
```

I would like to use each row in `G` as a multi-dimensional index into `gamma`, i.e. look up the values in `gamma` with `G`. More concretely, I want to get `array([16, 14])`, since

```py
>>> gamma[1, 2, 0]
16
>>> gamma[1, 1, 1]
14
```

I tried things like `gamma[G]` and `np.take(gamma, G)`, but nothing gives me the correct result.

Comment: You want something like this `gamma[ G[0][0] ][ G[0][1] ][ G[0][2] ]`?

Comment: think in terms of indexing with tuples, e.g. `gamma[(1, 2, 0)]`

Comment: @CarlHR Yes, except that `g.shape[1]` may not be 3.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! The answer is `np.array([gamma[tuple(idx)] for idx in G])`.

Comment: `gamma[tuple(g.T)]` is all you need.  Look at the `tuple(g.T)` by itself.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh I like that. Can confirm it works!